# Kubernetes manifest on Azure for port 443

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes

Battling with Kubernetes manifest on Azure.  I have a simple api app running on port `443 (https)`. I simply want to run and replicate this app 3 times within a kubernetes cluster with a load balancer.

**Kubernetes cluster:**

[image: Kubernetes cluster figure]

My manifest file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apiApp
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
   metadata:
   labels:
   app: apiApp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: apiApp
    image: {image name on Registry}
    ports:
    - containerPort: 443
      hostPort: 443
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apiApp
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    app: apiApp
```

In the above manifest the loadbalancer does not seem to find the app on port 443 within the container.

1) How can I create this manifest to link load balancer to port 443 of the  containers and also expose the load balancer to the outside world on port 443.

2)How would manifest look like in multi cluster environment (same conditions as above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, I did the test with the load balancer follow the document [Deploy an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough).

This example only has one pod, so I scale up the pod in to 3 with the command `kubectl scale --replicas=3 deployment/azure-vote-front`. The yaml file about scales and Load Balancer will like the screenshot below.

[image]
[image]

When the Cluster finish, I can access the service from Internet via Web Browse. And you can use the command [`az aks browse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-browse) to go into the Kubernets dashboard to get a overview of the Kubernets Cluster.

**Update**

The Azure Kubernets Cluster is just a resource group like below and so as the load balancer:
[image]

Comment: Hi Charles , so you saying I can simply change the port settings in this example to port 443. Does port 443 not conflict with master node in kubernetes cluster on same external IP address ?

Comment: Your development are just pods in node, and the pods access the Internet via the port on the host node. The architecture is like this: pod_port --> host_node_port --> loadbalancer --> Internet.

Comment: Thanks Charles , will report back on progress.  Any pointers on how the loadbalancer will look like in multi-cluster environment.

Comment: @user3385105 Well, the Kubernets Cluster acts as a resource group in Azure, I will update the answer with a screenshot for the cluster, so you can see the load balancer is also just a load balancer in the resource group as common.

Comment: @user3385105 If the answer is helpful or for more help, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Charles,  after 20 testing clusters in Azure finally got the problem.  In .net core app if you use  options.Listen( IPAddress.Any , 443)  in Kestrel then the app works. Any other combination like ListenLocalHost or IPAddress.Lookback does not work.  If you can update your answer to include this I can mark the answer as final.  plse confirm my observation first ,not sure why the other options don't work.

Comment: @user3385105 For kubernets pods, each one has a private IP, and they access the Internet only through the Load Balancer with port 443. And only options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443) listens to any IP from the pods to the port.443. The other two ways I think you know more than me.